Can I use Google SGE (Search Generative Experience) on MS Edge?
I have a question on Google SGE (Search Generative Experience).
In the official document, it says that Google SGE is supported on Chrome. When I tried it on Microsoft Edge, it worked for one of my devices but not for the other. (Both devices are Windows 11 and SGE worked for both devices on Chrome.)
I am wondering what is the reason why Google SGE can be used on Microsoft Edge for some devices but not for others.
I appreciate if you could provide me with your experience on this. Thank you.
